# tableView - sometimes with error, sometimes without - trying to load label in last cell

Tags: ios, tableview, cell, nsrangeexception

I am trying to implement a load more method to my last cell. After experimenting I finally could implement the load more (without function yet) to my cell. But it seems to be a bit harder, because I'm loading my content from a XML.

Here is what I do:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

   if([tabelle count]>= 10)
{
    return [tabelle count]+1;
}
else
{
    return [tabelle count];

}
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; }

    if(indexPath.row != [tabelle count] )
{

    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-Bold" size:14.0];
    cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12.0];
    self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    NSString *TableText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [[tabelle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] number1]]; 
    NSString *TableText2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [[tabelle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] number2]];  

    NSString *cellValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", TableText2];
    NSString *cellValue2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", TableText];
    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:51.0f/255.0f green:102.0f/255.0f blue:220.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = cellValue2;

}
else if(indexPath.row==[tabelle count])

{
    UILabel *loadMore =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0,0,320,30)];
    loadMore.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    loadMore.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    loadMore.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:20];
    loadMore.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
    loadMore.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
    loadMore.text=@"Gimme more!";
    [cell addSubview:loadMore];
}
return cell;
```

}

The load more cell (that reads Gimme more!) pops up on the last cell (but not creating a new last cell, just on the normal last cell, therefore interfering with its content) and also pops up randomly over the tableview.

The first problem was, that it bit itself with this method, so I had to alter it a little bit, otherwise I get the error below:

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (indexPath.row == [tabelle count]) {

} else {
    NSString *text = [[self.tabelle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] number1];

    CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.tableView.frame.size.width - PADDING * 7, 1000.0f)];
    return textSize.height + PADDING * 7;
}
}

  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
{
    if(indexPath.row==[tabelle count])
    {
        [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}
```

}
And here is the error I had (and sometimes still have when scrolling through the view):

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 11 beyond bounds [0 .. 10]'
```

Comment: You seem to be returning the same number of rows for each section. Shouldn't you be restricting the count?

Comment: Do you mean in the numberOfRowsInSection?

Comment: Yes. You need to take the section number into account when returning the number of rows. If you're using a variant of my code - you only want to return 1 for the second section if there are more items to display and 0 if there are no more items to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be some oddities with the code you posted. In the first snippet the if-statement seems to float by itself (no encapsulating method?). In heightForRowAtIndexPath you're not returning a value from the then section of the if-statement.

[EDIT]
This is how I would write what you have posted so far:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // I am not the below make sense but that depends on what you are intending
    // I do have a feeling there is a "off by one" issue here
    if ([tabelle count] >= 10) {
        return [tabelle count]+1;
    }else{
        return [tabelle count];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    if (indexPath.row != [tabelle count] ) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell1"];
        if (cell == nil) {
            [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell1"]; }

            cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-Bold" size:14.0];
            cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12.0];
            cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:51.0f/255.0f green:102.0f/255.0f blue:220.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
            self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        }
        NSString *TableText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [[tabelle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] number1]]; 
        NSString *TableText2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [[tabelle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] number2]];  

        cell.textLabel.text = TableText;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = TableText2;
    }else{
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell2"];
        if (cell == nil) {
            [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell2"]; }
            UILabel *loadMore = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0,0,320,30)];
            loadMore.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            loadMore.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            loadMore.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
            loadMore.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
            loadMore.text = @"Gimme more!";
            [cell addSubview:loadMore];
        }
    }
    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == [tabelle count]) {
        return 44.0;
    }else{
        NSString *text = [[self.tabelle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] number1];
        CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.tableView.frame.size.width - PADDING * 7, 1000.0f)];
        return textSize.height + PADDING * 7;
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    if (indexPath.row == [tabelle count]) {
        // TO-DO: user tapped 'Giimie more'
    }else{
        // TO-DO: user tapped a regular cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the first if is in the cellForRowAtIndex method. And in the second one I have tbh I didn't know what to put for the first if.

Comment: Can you post the rest of the cellForRowAtIndex code? In the second one I would return the default height of 44.0 in that then-leaf.

Comment: Why are you calling cellForRowAtIndexPath in didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: The method is not yet done, I'm not that familiar with tableView yet and trying to call the next entries (Also as of now, it just displays all entries, somehow ignoring that I only want to call 10)

Comment: I think there is a problem in cellForRowAtIndex. You're dequeueing cells as you should but you really have two different kinds of cells: the normal ones and the 'gimmie more'. You probably want to either clear out the fields of the cell of the other type or you'll want to dequeue by cell type (ie move the "is this cell 10" test up.

Comment: What do you mean by clear out? The Dequeueing (is this cell 10 test) didn't work. Still shows me all my entries and in the last cell displays "gimme more!"

Comment: Thanks for the update, I changed my code accordingly. But on startup I get Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out: Just a bracket on the wrong line. Thanks :) Its appreciated! But I still have the problem that it displays more than ten entries. Do you maybe know why that is?

Comment: In numberOfRowsInSection you tell it that there are > 10 cells.

Comment: Yes, but it's just the check, if there are more or exactly ten. If so it adds the "Gimme more!". I still have to figure out how to limit it to ten entries.